Rigid body object falling into the plane

My objects fall and some of them go half into the plane.
Although my ojects are tilted in different angles at keyframe - 0 , at keyframe 2, they all turn flat and then fall. Can someone help me with this please?


Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/
